# Django Rest Framework way to ingest json data?

Tags: python, json, django, rest

Hey guys I'm trying to ingest some data from a third party API when a DRF endpoint is called.

I can easily build the get request using urllib2 and deserialize the json, but is there some way to use django serializers and do it the drf way? Or am I just overthinking this?

```
import json, urllib2


class IngestThirdPartyView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        data = request.data
        url = 'https://third_party.com/media/{}'.format(data['item_id]')
        response = urllib.urlopen(url)
        # Handle item somehow
        item = json.load(response)
```

Any suggestions for a more DRF friendly way to handle this are very much welcome!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

From your example code,

```
import requests

class IngestThirdPartyView():
    def post(self, request):
        data = request.data
        url = 'https://third_party.com/media/{}'.format(data['item_id]')
        item = requests.get(url).json() # this will retrieve json response
        # then you could deserialize the above json and validate it or something 
        # as described here in docs http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#deserializing-objects
        # Handle item somehow
```